# Autolayout NSScrollview does not grow contentView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout

I have a scrollview that I'm trying to setup with auto layout.

The actual content is in a container view, this container view a set of visible box views. They are added without any problem to the container view. Each one is given a couple of constraints

```
NSViewController prev;
for(NSViewController *lvc in vcs) {
//each view is padded by 5 from left
    [containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lvc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:prev.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:5]];
//Constant height
    [containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lvc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:300]];
//Constant width
    [containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lvc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0 constant:300]];
prev = lvc;

}


[_scrollView setDocumentView:containerView];
[_scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:listContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:_scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

However the scroll view does not allow the container view to grow without growing the scrollview itself. The right edge of the `containerView` is attached to the right edge of the scroll view. If I grow the scroll view I can see there's more content from the list container view but only as big as the scroll view is.

The last row is my attempt to fix this by basically saying "let the container view grow larger than the scroll view". Isn't that the correct way of setting the constraint?

Comment: You might consider using an `NSStackView` for container view, although that doesn't directly solve this problem. (See [this email list thread](http://markmail.org/message/noeabbp5noptyla6) for a discussion.) Also, adding a constraint (your last line) can never increase flexibility. That constraint may itself allow flexibility but does not override any other constraints, possibly set up by the scroll view or the clip view, that are more restrictive. Is your scroll view set up entirely in code or is it in a NIB or storyboard?

Comment: I'll look into NSStackView and the thread asap. I have an outlet in my .m for the scrollview (i.e. setup in NIB). I wonder if it's a good idea/possible to remove the constraints of the scrollview and proceed from there by adding custom constraints?

Comment: You should not attempt to modify or remove any constraints that you did not create and add. The best way to control the constraints within the scroll view is to set up the document view in the NIB and set the constraints there, as discussed in that email thread. If you make the document view a stack view, you can add the subviews to it in code similar to what you're doing (except the stack view will take care of spacing between the subviews).

Comment: @KenThomases thanks for the email list thread. Worked great! You may/should obviously post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `NSStackView` to your NIB and then select Editor > Embed In > Scroll View. Add constraints to the scroll view to keep it laid out relative to its superview and/or sibling views. Add constraints between the stack view and its superview (the clip view) to keep its top and leading edges the same as the clip view's. Add a constraint to keep the stack view's trailing edge greater than or equal to the clip view's trailing edge. Add a constraint to the keep the stack view's bottom edge greater than or equal to the clip view's bottom edge.

In your code, add the views of the view controllers in `vcs` as subviews of the stack view. The stack view's spacing will default to 8. In your code, you set spacing of 5. So, you can change the stack view's spacing to 5. (This can be done in the NIB.)

Comment: Thanks. Just one follow-up question, not sure if this should be a new question. But how should I remove views from NSStackView if I want to redraw with a different set of subviews. How are the constraints maintained etc.

Comment: You add a view using `-addView:inGravity:` or `-insertView:atIndex:inGravity:`. You remove a view using `-[NSStackView removeView:]`. You can completely replace the set of views in a gravity area using `-setViews:inGravity:`. The stack view is responsible for managing the constraints it uses. If your views have their own internal constraints (e.g. height or width constraints), you manage those.